# How to get only the colums I want to move to new dataframe with this code?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiple-columns

I am trying to select only 2 columns from a csv file: `Body` and `CreatedDate`.
`CreatedDate` looks like this: `2018-08-07T12:36:11.000Z`.
`Body` is just text of work being done. Some `Body` cells are empty so I only want the ones with data in it.

I have tried using the code below to just get only the 2 desired columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df1= df['CreatedDate'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Body'].map(str)
print(df1)
```

I am getting the entire `df` printed twice. I see this:

> [10 rows x 15 columns] & [15 rows x 10 columns]

at the bottom of each print. I am expecting to only see my 2 chosen columns. Why am I seeing all of `df` twice on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options for [indexing a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). This particular one can be done on a single line.

```
import pandas as pd
# read the csv into df
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
# take only the rows where 'Body' has a value and only columns ['Body', 'CreatedDate']
df = df.loc[df['Body'].notnull(),['Body', 'CreatedDate']]
print(df)
```

You may also want to read up on [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Comment: That did it! Thanks!